# How can I copy a sheet and have my macros still work?

Tags: excel, vba

First off I want to apologize if my question has already been answered elsewhere as I did spend some time searching.

I'm using two macros in a sheet (very simple macros... they filter a table) and this sheet is a template that will be used every week. When I copy the sheet and make a new one, the macros no longer work. The error I receive is Runtime Error 9; Subscript out of range. I looked at the VBA code (which I've never really learned VBA) and see it is referencing a table title. Is there a way to fix this so it doesn't reference that specific table but rather the cells contained in that table? Example of the title name:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1619").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
```

I want to access the data from a cell range of `A103:A113`. I tried this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Range("$A$103:$A$113").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

This didn't work either but the error I received was different. `"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"`

What I know would work is if there was a way to have the same table name across all sheets but my limited research has seemed to point me in the direction of this not being possible.

Comment: It's impossible to reference `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Range("$A$103:$A$113")` like this - either as above in your first sample, OR convert table to normal range and then use `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$103:$A$113")`.

Comment: That worked! If you wouldn't mind, could you post that as an answer and I'll give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to reference `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Range("$A$103:$A$113")` like this - either as above in your first sample, OR convert table to normal range and then use `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$103:$A$113")`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend converting a table to a normal range - the tables are quite useful and one can access all elements either with `.Range` or `.DataBodyRange` depending on the needs. Using `worksheet.Range` and hardcoding the range address is a recipe for a future bug - the moment the sheet structure changes or the table gets extended!

Comment: @PeterAlbert I have nothing to decline here, it's up to OP to decide which suits best his needs - I know many cases when simplicity is more important than flexibility, and such solutions happily work ages)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that you access the Range through a Table/ListObject - but the ListObject changes the name during the copy, as each Table must have a unique name. The solution is simple - instead of accessing the ListObject with its name, simply use the index in the worksheet - that will not change. Therefore, replace

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1619").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
```

(assuming it is the only/first table in the worksheet.)